# Second Click into Datepicker Input Field is Clearing Value

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the native Chrome datepicker with datetime-local because it fits the needs we have:

```
<div class="form-group" id="schedule-div">
  <div><label for="meeting-time">Schedule</label></div>
  <input type="datetime-local" class="job-schedule form-control" id="schedule">
</div>
```

And in order to set the "min" value to be today's date I am using some jQuery like so:

```
$("#schedule").on("click", function (e) {
  const min = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 16);
  $("#schedule").attr("min", min);
});
```

This solves the issue of setting the "min" date to be today. However, the problem I'm running into is that, right next to the date in the input box is a section to enter the time. The problem is that once I've selected the correct day, when I click within the "time" part of the input field, it clears the input - so the date I just selected via the datepicker disappears. I assume this is because my "click" triggers my jQuery all over again.

How can I handle this so the date doesn't clear when I click back into the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `on` to `one` and it should work :)

```
$("#schedule").one("click", function (e) {
  const min = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 16);
  $("#schedule").attr("min", min);
});
```

This makes your click `event` just run once.